# Fortran - Pulling Strings Containing Only Specified Characters

Tags: database, string, fortran, character

I have a Fortran project that I am working on that requires scanning through a database and storing strings that only contain characters specified by a reference string.

For example, supposed I have a reference string "A11." The database contains several pieces of data some of which contain all of the characters in the reference and some that do not, the following set is an example of this:

"A111,
"A211"
"B11"
"1AA1"

In this case, the program only pulls "A111," and "1AA1," because the other strings contain characters not in the reference string "A11."

I tried using a variant of this code, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 program main
 implicit none
 integer :: iostatus, i
 character*6, dimension(:), allocatable :: mystr_temp
 character*6 :: refstr
 open(unit=2,file='file.txt')
 iostatus = 1
 i = 1
 refstr = 'Ref'
 mystr(1) = ''
 do while (iostatus > 0)
      do while (any(mystr(i)) /= any(refstr))
           read(2,'(A6)', iostat = iostatus) mystr(i)
      end do
      i = i + 1
 end do
 end program main
```

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the errors that either your compiler reports or that you find at run time if the code compiles.  It's obvious to me that your code shouldn't compile, the array `mystr` in line 10 of your snippet has not previously been declared.  Perhaps you are confusing `mystr_temp` and `mystr`.  If you are going to modify your question be sure to include the errors that your compiler reports or that you see at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can probably do this by using [verify(str1,str2)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/VERIFY.html), which returns the location of the first character in `str1` not present in `str2`. If all the characters in `str1` are found in `str2`, the function returns `0`. So I have modified the code such that

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer :: ios, i
    character(6) :: mystr(100), refstr, stmp
    open(unit=2,file='file.txt')

    i = 0
    refstr = 'A11'
    do
        read(2, '(a6)', iostat=ios) stmp
        if ( ios /= 0 ) exit
        if ( verify( stmp, refstr ) == 0 ) then
            i = i + 1
            mystr(i) = stmp
            print *, i, ":", mystr(i)
        endif
    enddo
end program
```

which gives for the sample data in the question

```
       1 :A111
       2 :1AA1
```